Remove all commits that only update timestamp in a file
I have a git repository where I am the only contributor and there are zero forks of the repository. This means I can do whatever I want in terms of rebases and forced pushes.
The repository has 22503 commits. The history is linear, there are no merge commits. Most commits only change file, github-metrics.svg and a lot of commits only change one line somewhere at the bottom with this text:
                <span>Last updated $(TIMESTAMP) with lowlighter/metrics@$(VERSION)</span>

I would like to "clean up" this repository by removing all commits that only have this change. If a commit has this change and another change, then it should stay.
If I had to do this manually for a small number of commits, then I would do git rebase --interactive, and for every commit that only changes the "Last updated", I would change that commit to a fixup. I already tried it manually for about a dozen commits and the results are satisfactory.
However I have over 22k commits so it becomes impossible to do manually. How can I automate this?
The following questions are similar but different:

Git: Remove commits which only changes a timestamp - this completely deletes the line with the timestamp and I don't want that.
Can git ignore some specific line from git status? - this approach could work to avoid adding new commits with only timestamp changes but it has 2 problems (1) it doesn't change commits that already exist (2) in requires a file in the .git directory so that means it will only work on my local repository, not for example on a repository on GitHub that is updated by GitHub Actions.

Update 01/05/2024
I wrote this shell script:
#!/bin/bash -e

# Define the metrics file name
metrics_file="github-metrics.svg"

# Function to validate the number of arguments
validate_arguments() {
  if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Error: Incorrect number of arguments. Usage: $0 <commit>"
    exit 0
  fi
}

# Function to check if the commit exists
check_commit_existence() {
  git rev-parse --quiet --verify "$1^{commit}" >/dev/null ||
    { echo "Error: Commit $1 does not exist"; exit 0; }
}

# Function to check if the parent commit exists
check_commit_parent_existence() {
  git rev-parse --quiet --verify "$1^" >/dev/null ||
    { echo "Error: Parent of commit $1 does not exist"; exit 0; }
}

# Function to check if the metrics file exists
check_metrics_exists() {
  git cat-file -e "$1:$metrics_file" ||
    { echo "Error: $metrics_file does not exist in commit $1"; exit 0; }
}

# Function to check for changes in metrics file
check_metrics_changes() {
  short_stat=$(git diff --shortstat "$1^" "$1" "$metrics_file")
  if [ -z "$short_stat" ]; then
    echo "Error: No changes in $metrics_file"
    exit 0
  fi
}

# Function to check for excessive changes
check_excessive_changes() {
  git diff --shortstat "$1^" "$1" | grep -q '^ 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)' ||
    { echo "Error: Too many changes in $1"; exit 0; }
}

# Function to check for last updated change
check_last_updated_change() {
  git_diff_output=$(git diff "$1^" "$1" --unified=0 --word-diff | tail +6)
  search_string='<span>Last updated .+, .+ \(timezone [A-Za-z/]+\) with lowlighter/metrics@[0-9.]+</span>'
  if ! echo "$git_diff_output" | grep --quiet -E "$search_string"; then
    echo "Error: No change to Last updated"
    exit 0
  fi
}

# Main function
main() {
  validate_arguments "$@"
  check_commit_existence "$1"
  check_commit_parent_existence "$1"
  check_metrics_exists "$1"
  check_metrics_changes "$1"
  check_excessive_changes "$1"
  #check_last_updated_change "$1"

  # Get the metrics file from the parent commit
  git checkout "$1^" "$metrics_file"
}

# Call the main function with passed arguments
main "$@"

and I run it with
git filter-branch --tree-filter '~/bin/lastupdated.sh $GIT_COMMIT' HEAD

This runs for about 20 minutes, and at the end I still have commits that have only that one line change.
Where did it go wrong?

Sounds like you can use git filter-branch --commit-filter and call skip_commit "$@"; in the filter command when you detect that $GIT_COMMIT contains only a timestamp change.

Detecting such a change is probably easiest using git show -G<regex> and/or some stream text editor

Is your history linear or do you have some merge commits, and if you have merge commits, do they ever resolve conflicts? (I don't actually know if this matters yet, but if the history is linear, or if all merges didn't have conflicts, at least an automated rebase is one possible solution.)

BTW, I think your test is a little different than the wording of your ask, which sounds like you want to "drop" the commits when that is the only change. But your test did a "fixup" instead of a "drop", which means that it modified an earlier commit with the higher version numbers. With fixup, those commits that you wish to keep would be modified by later commits that only changed the version. My gut feeling is "drop" is better than "fixup" here, and maybe you add one commit at the end for the final version that you are at now.

You are correct that it is a little different, but that little difference is acceptable for me. Either way is ok.

My history is linear. No merge commits.

git show -G"Last updated" would always show every commit because the timestamp is always updated. I want to know when there are no other changes. So if there are other changes, do nothing.

I tried to make this work with filter-branch, but totally failed due to the current commit not being available in the filters. It might be possible with git filter-repo --commit-callback.
So my next attempt was to git rebase. It should be possible to come up with a custom GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR which modifies the todo list accordingly, but I went for a solution that's a bit more hacky: git rebase -x. It's inefficient, but it gets the task done.
$ cat >edit.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
head="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"

if ! git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD^ >/dev/null; then
  echo "Ignoring root commit $head" >&2
  exit 0
fi

if ! git diff --exit-code HEAD^ HEAD -- ':!github-metrics.svg' >/dev/null; then
  # changes in other files, keep commit
  echo "Other files changed, keeping commit $head" >&2
  exit 0
fi

if git diff -U0 HEAD^ HEAD -- 'github-metrics.svg' | tail +6 | grep -qv '<span>Last updated .* with lowlighter/metrics@.*</span>'; then
  # other lines changed in metrics svg, keep commit
  echo "Other lines in metrics file changed, keeping commit $head" >&2
  exit 0
fi

# only timestamp was updated, drop commit
echo "Only timestamp changed, dropping commit" >&2
git reset --soft HEAD^
git commit --amend --no-edit
exit 0
EOF
$ chmod +x edit.sh
$ git rebase -x ./edit.sh

This creates a todo list similar to the following:
pick 7d03915c Commit message one
exec ./edit.sh
pick 9de881c4 Commit message two
exec ./edit.sh
pick 0b0e07b8 Commit message three
exec ./edit.sh
pick 038655e9 Commit message four
exec ./edit.sh
pick ade63693 Commit message five
exec ./edit.sh
pick 43f578d2 Commit message six
exec ./edit.sh

After each commit, the script is executed. It performs the following steps in order:

Is it a root commit (i.e. doesn't have a parent)? → Don't do anything, keep commit
Does the commit change files other than github-metrics.svg? → Don't do anything, keep commit
Does the commit change other lines than the "Last updated" line in the svg? → Don't do anything, keep commit
All prior checks failed. This means that only the timestamp line was modified. → Fuse the commit and its parent by soft-resetting and amending (basically a "fixup").

Several important things to note:

Make a backup before you run this!
Manually verify the resulting history!
It is slow(-ish)
It creates lots of temporary commits that might be amended in the next step
It flattens the history, i.e. removes any merge commits (and any changes from "evil merges")
The timestamp is always fixed-up into the previous commit, which is kind of confusing. More intuitive would be a forward-fixup (i.e. fuse into the child), but I was unable to figure out a simple way to do so – maybe it is possible by reversing the list, running the change detection, then reversing again (I haven't tried).

A proper GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR approach would probably use a similar script, running the change detection from the script on each commit line in the original todo list and replacing pick with fixup if only the timestamp was modified. Feel free to take some inspiration from my answer on how to squash commits with the same commit message.
